# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - running slowly and consuming a lot of RAM

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've been running VS2010 Professional for some time, and recently upgraded to Ultimate (installed on top of Professional).

Ever since, the memory usage seems a lot higher (~ 150MB in idle with no project loaded), the initial loading of the product is a lot slower, and general performance is slow.

Is there any way to finetune performance of Visual Studio? (For example, disable some functionality of it, etc)

Comment: Turn off/disable all of your add-ins and extensions. A *lot* of them cause performance problems, and the rest of them just take their toll on an already-taxed processor. Resharper is notorious for this...

Comment: i am not using resharper at the time

Comment: Do you have *any* add-ins or extensions installed?

Comment: Not too many - NuGet and Productivity power tools. The application itself seems a lot of heavier than the Professional version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to tools => options => And look through the addons that you may have installed. When i upgraded from Professional to Ultimate on the same machine i faced the same issue.

- I went through VS power tools and disabled features i did not use (tools=>options=>power tools)
- I went through Intellitrace and disabled it, it has two running modes, basic and advanced, former is lighter but try turning it off completely to see if that helps
- When you load VS, the home page loads the last 10 solutions/projects you worked on before. I would recommend changing that to 1-2 to begin with
- You could also disable the new and alerts on the VS 2010 home screen. This would help decrease the load time
- Go to tools and Extension manager and review your list of add ons and uninstall any that you might not need
- Another thing that i did was, by default many tool bars such as 'Debugging', 'css', etc etc get loaded when you open a project. Get rid of all the toolbars by right clicking on the toolbar space and unchecking them all, give it a clean start and add only the ones you need.

  - If nothing else helps, delete the .suo file (Which stores the default setting for the solution you are working on), might be corrupt, and start again.

You can run visual studio with the following command line switch to load devenv without any extensions devenv.exe /resetaddin http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=VS.100).aspx

You could always look at the task manager to profile the resources being consumed. Or even better from the command line run devenv /log output.txt to log all activities performed by VS during the load, may be you would get some hints from there.

HTH
Cheers, Tarun

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. I forgot about Intellitrace. at the time i am not using it at all.

Comment: Btw, intellitrace is indeed a memory sucker, we tried running it in production to get a log to capture some nasty non reproducible issues, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2009/11/16/intellitrace-itrace-files.aspx but though we ran the trace during off peak, the users still felt the lag in application response.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest versions of your addons (if any), the Intellisense that comes with VS tends to be slow and use a lot of cache space (ReSharper has a nice one). Those are just some I can think up off the top of my head. Also large projects tend to use a lot of memory (but 150mb idle seems normal as that's what I get on my machine as well with everything disabled). It's just that VS is a bulky application because it does so much.

Comment: Any general VS performance tuning tips? or any link for that?

Comment: ReSharper is a paid Addon but I would definitely recommend turning off the intellisense as that usually causes some lag issues. Other than that its a good application (2008 was worse in terms of memory use sometimes). I've never found a way to make it use less memory idling (uses 4gb on this large project for me).